# Is it possible to save Google/Bing Map in browser's cache?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, browser, bing-maps, offline

My current website project needs to enable users to view offline Google/Bing Maps. I'm using Google Map now but it needs to be connected to the Internet each time you open the webpage so that you can see the map. In offline mode, you'll see nothing on the map. The reason I guess is the follows:

```
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

Because each time the webpage initializes, the browser tries to visit the above library link. I know that an Android app can store a portion of Google Map to the local file system, and guess an iOS app would probably also be able to do so. However, when it comes to website, is it possible to store a portion of Google/Bing Map in the browser's cache?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Using_the_application_cache would be a starting point.

Comment: I don't think so. Manifest is used to store a webpage or resource file instead of Google Map data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're unlikely to be able to achieve this with Google or Bing maps. The major issue being that when a user zooms in/out, different images are loaded in dynamically.

I'd therefore backtrack and say 'Why do I need to use Google Maps?':

a) **because I want to indicate the location of something on a map**

Use an image instead

b) **I want to allow my user to zoom in on the map and interact with it**

There are a number of mapping solutions that allow you to use your own SVG maps (or maps from Wikipedia) e.g. http://jqvmap.com/

You can host all of the assets and thus this can work offline via App Cache/Manifest.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is great! But the example map is too coarse to use. Is there any vector map with the detail of showing individual buildings?

Comment: Let me try OpenStreetMap.